# Light effect with image magick

Tags: image, imagemagick, effects

I'm using ImageMagick to resize an image to a smaller size gif. In this process I'm trying to give the image a light effect, not a side-light, just like a shiny look all over. Not a good comparison but for a better understanding think of an image seen in a old screen or an image seen in glossy monitor - I'm trying to enhance the image the closest to this point. An important point is that I can't make a image-to-image treatment, it must be something that I can use in all the images. I know ImageMagick is a powerful tool, and can certainly do something for my images!
Many thanks!

Closest example:
http://images.sixrevisions.com/2009/05/01-02_high_pass_filter.jpg

Comment: Can you link to an example of what you're hoping to accomplish?

Comment: I just added a url with an example - it's not quite what I need, because I don't need so much sharpening - the images are not as "difficult" as this one with the cat, but the more light/shine effect it's what I look for! Thank you for the comment

Answer (score 1):

I'm still a bit confused by what you're trying to accomplish, but maybe these will get you going in the right direction.

Based upon the high pass filter example, you may want to check out [this page](http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/binomial/index.php), especially about two-thirds of the way down under "High Pass Filtering Of A True Color Image", and the "High Pass Darkened" example a bit further down under "Filtering With Bias".

The color in the example also seems a bit more exaggerated, so you may want to look at [Adjustments Using Histogram Modification](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/color/#histogram).

Before you had posted the example, I thought you were looking for some kind of reflection effect, like a glass button (which you can find examples for [here](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/advanced/), along with a bunch of other interesting effects).

If this doesn't meet your needs and you can be a bit more specific, please update your post...I'm sure somebody here can help you.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to use a mask. See [this post](http://nadiana.com/pil-tutorial-how-create-button-generator#Very_simple_button_effect) for an example. It uses Python and PIL but the same thing can be done using ImageMagick.

Comment: Than you for the suggestion. I already have an effect like that alpha layer at the edges, like an emboss effect. What I'm trying to achieve now has more to do with the image itself!